# Is it normal for a soldier whom got healed ended up hurt at the end of the mission?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I find it strange that I healed two soldiers but they show up hurt when they return.

Here is a screenshot of them:
[image]

Is it suppose to be normal???

Comment: If not for this you could just use up all medkits before pulling out and that would be too powerful. And realistically, medics are field triage, they can't provide the same kind of healing as your doctors and surgeons back at the ship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. Once a soldier takes HP damage, they're injured, even if a medkit gets used. This is just one of the reasons the medkit is considered worthless.

Comment: Ok  so the idea is just using the medic kit to keep your soldiers alive thru the mission but it won't reduce the amount of time they have to stay in the infirmary. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Although I swear I remember some perk the medic could get that made it so the healing they did was permanent...

Comment: Medkits aren't worthless, they are used to stay alive... very much needed.

Comment: While the answer is correct, calling Medkits "worthless" is somewhat out of place. Besides keeping your soldiers alive during tactical, they also grant immunity to poison.

Comment: @SaintWacko 99.9% sure that is not the case, at least not in vanilla (without mods).